# Is there a way to find users with a field with null value?

Tags: c#, null, query-string, scim

How do I search for users with external id with null values?
I'm reading section 3.4.2.2 (filtering) of the RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-7.8). I would like to write a correct query string and I know that PR operator, it should be for the attribute != null. For example:

- filter SCIM syntax : ?filter=externalId pr
- SQL syntax : externalId is not null
- List item

How do I search for null values? Is there a way to write a "Not Pr" or another operator?

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the specification, it appears there are a few ways you could express what you want:

- `filter=not externalId pr`
- `filter=not (externalId pr)`
- `filter=externalId eq null`

Comment: If you want to use "not" operation, you need to use grouping always I think.  ABNF: *1"not" "(" FILTER ")"

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question looking for an answer to my own SCIM question.

I noticed you are filtering and not searching

Filtering is different than searching in an important way: Not all fields are available to filtering like they are searching.

It will depend on implementation but generally filtering will only have the most common filter fields available to it. (internal)Id, login, maybe lastName

externalId looks like it's possibly a custom field, or if not custom, ancillary.